# Can I autowire a grails service to java src classes

Tags: grails

I have a grails service which i would like to access from other libraries

How Can I autowire a Grails service from java classes located in grails-app `SRC` folder ?

Answer (score 1):

> How Can I autowire a Grails service from java classes located in grails-app SRC folder ?

In `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy` you can create a bean definition using something like this...

```
beans = {
    someBeanName com.packagename.SomeJavaClass
}
```

If you want that bean to be auto wired by name you could do something like this:

```
beans = {
    someBeanName(com.packagename.SomeJavaClass) { bean ->
        bean.autowire = 'byName'
    }
}
```

That would work for something like this:

```
// src/java/com/packagename/SomeJavaClass.java
package com.packagename;

public class SomeJavaClass {
    private MoneyService moneyService;

    // if you have a moneyService bean in the context,
    // it will be auto wired here
    public void setMoneyService(MoneyService svc) {
        moneyService = svc;
    }
}
```

You could also use the `@Autowired` annotation in your class if you didn't want to do the `bean.autowire = 'byName'` business in `resources.groovy`.

You have all of the options that come along with Spring.

I hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, if you are trying to go in the other direction and wire a Java class into your service, your services are automatically auto wired by name so you can just add the Java bean to the application context and then declare a property in the service that is the same as the bean name.

Service:

```
// grails-app/services/com/packagename/MoneyService.groovy
package com.packagename

class MoneyService {
    def someBeanName
}
```

Bean definition:

```
// grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy
beans = {
    someBeanName com.packagename.SomeJavaClass
}
```